# how to sync textfields in html

Tags: html, duplicates, textfield, synchronization

I have multipul input fields on a page, a few of them are type="textfield"
and some of those textfields i want to group, 
so that if i type something into one of them it propergates to the rest within that group.

I have tried using the same name as radio buttons work like this, but that doesn't seem to work.
i have looked around the net but cannot find any examples.

does anyone know how to do this, or anywhere which tells you how?

Regards

chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with pure html, have you tried using JavaScript? I would look into jQuery to set up event handlers for that.

```
$('textbox1').change(function(o) {
    $('textbox2').val($(o).val());
}
```

Will react to all changes of textbox1 and replicate the value to textbox2. Untested code, only an approach.

Comment: thanks i used javascript in this example, but a messy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery since version 1.7 offers a convenient way to handle several events by using the .on()  handler - method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textbox1').on('keypress keyup change', function(event) {
            $('#textbox2').val(event.target.value);
    });
});
```